# What is the Linux / UNIX command to display each character of a string in new line?

Tags: linux, unix

what is the linux command / how  to display each character of a string in new line ?
Example :
Input string : `abc123`

Output (all the characters are in new lines):

```
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `sed`:

```
echo abc123 | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'
```

Explatnaion of `sed` regex:

- `s`: substitute
- `\(.\)`: each single character
- `\1\n`: replace the matched character by the same and a Linefeed
- `g`: do not stop at first match